# sed multiple remembered patterns

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a series of strings that are similar to the following (but they can be more complicated):

```
echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old"
```

I want to print only the first pattern (17). I tried using sed using:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y].*/\1/'
```

but it prints me every time the last pattern listed (69 in this case).

How can I force sed to print the first or the second pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: sed returns always the longest match, since your pattern begins with `.*`, you obtain the substring that starts at the begining of the string until the last 2 digits followed by a space or an "y"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the first `.*` with `[^0-9]*` because `.*` at the first greedily matches all the characters upto the last two digits.

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y].*/\1/'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y].*/\1/'
17
```

To print the second number.

```
$ echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" | sed 's/^[^0-9]*[0-9][0-9][ y][^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y].*/\1/'
44
```

**OR**

To get the number one by one,

```
sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y]\)\{1\}.*/\2/' file
```

Just change `1` inside the curly braces `{}` to `2` in the above regex to display the 2nd number. Change to `3` for the third number, and it goes on.

Example:

```
$ echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" | sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y]\)\{1\}.*/\2/'
17
$ echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" | sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y]\)\{2\}.*/\2/'
44
$ echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" | sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)[ y]\)\{3\}.*/\2/'
69
```

Comment: `How can I force sed to print the first or the second pattern?` ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: `I  want to print only the first pattern (17)`

Comment: @shelter; use group of pattern (not keeped) before the element to print like `\([^0-9]+[0-9]+\)\{3\}` for removing the first 3 element

Comment: Thank you to you all for the prompt answers. I tried them all and I found the solution from @AvinashRaj to be most universal across different OS.

Answer (score 5):

Use `grep -o` to extract the numbers, store them in an array, then you can choose which one you want:

```
line="I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" ^C

numbers=( $(grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' <<< "$line") )

# index from the start of the array
echo "First: ${numbers[0]}"
echo "Second: ${numbers[1]}"
# index from the end of the array
echo "Last: ${numbers[-1]}"
echo "2nd Last: ${numbers[-2]}"
```

```
First: 17
Second: 44
Last: 69
2nd Last: 44
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the pattern is the starting `.*` which is greedy and would consume as much as characters as it can. So here it would consume until it see the last digits in the string.

**Print first pattern**

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]).*/\1/'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]).*/\1/'
17
```

**Print second pattern**

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]).*/\2/'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "I am 17 y/o, I live at 44 Main street, and my mother is 69years old" | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9][0-9]).*/\2/'
44
```

Comment: The only drawback with this solution is that it does not give the freedom to pick any of the 3 numbers in the string but just the first 2 (this is a problem if I do not know how many numbers there). but thanks anyway!

Comment: @davide If you are looking for the freedom to select the nth number then [glenn jackman's answer would be the best pick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27970456/3150943)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk, just define your "pattern" and print the numeric occurrence of it, e.g.:

```
$ gawk -v FPAT="[0-9]{2}" '{print $1}' file
17
$ gawk -v FPAT="[0-9]{2}" '{print $2}' file
44
$ gawk -v FPAT="[0-9]{2}" '{print $3}' file
69
```